# Create a Google Dataproc cluster and connect to an external remote Hive metastore

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, hive-metastore

I am trying to create a dataproc cluster and point to a remote Hive metastore in order to access the Hive tables from this cluster. I am using the below create cluster command to create a Dataproc 2.0 cluster with connection to remote Hive metastore:

**Create Cluster Command:**

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create wl1-cluster-1 \
--region us-east1 \
--subnet projects/shared-vpc-admin/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/dev-us-east1-01 \
--enable-component-gateway \
--no-address \
--scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-32 \
--master-boot-disk-size 1000 \
--num-workers 10 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-32 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 1000 \
--image-version 2.0-debian10 \
--properties 'spark:spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3.0,spark:spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=maven,hive:hive.metastore.schema.verification=false,hive:javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://test-mysql.gcp-dev.glb.us.mycompany.net:3306/metastore,hive:javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=metastore,hive:javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=XXXX' \
--project sample_gcp_project
```

But it is failing during the step activate-component-hive-metastore.

**Error Message:**

```
<13>Sep 10 05:47:06 google-dataproc-startup[1734]: <13>Sep 10 05:47:06 activate-component-hive-metastore[3064]: nc: connect to wl1-cluster-1-m port 9083 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
<13>Sep 10 05:47:07 google-dataproc-startup[1734]: <13>Sep 10 05:47:07 activate-component-hive-metastore[3064]: nc: connect to wl1-cluster-1-m port 9083 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
<13>Sep 10 05:47:07 google-dataproc-startup[1734]: <13>Sep 10 05:47:07 activate-component-hive-metastore[3064]: 'nc -v -z -w 1 wl1-cluster-1-m 9083' attempt 23 failed! Sleeping 1s.
```

Few questions:

1. Is this the correct and only way to connect to a remote hive metastore while creating a cluster?
2. Instead of configuring the cluster with connection to remote hive metastore, can I access the hive metastore from a spark job submitted from this cluster. Can you please point me in the right direction?
3. Is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: The only property you need is `--properties hive:hive.metastore.uris=<metastore-uri>`. Could you add more info about where the external Hive is? Is it Dataproc Metastore service? Or is it in another cluster?

Comment: @Dagang the external Hive is in a different cluster. I am not sure if it is a Dataproc Metastore service but we can access it it from other dataproc clusters.

Comment: By default there is a Metastore service running on the (1st) master node of a Dataproc cluster, the  port is 9083, and Hive Server2 is configured to use the Metastore on the same node, if you need to point to the Metastore of another cluster, try `--properties hive:hive.metastore.uris=thrift://<another-cluster-master-node>:9083`. BTW, the 2 clusters need to be in the same VPC network in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is a Metastore service running on the (1st) master node of a Dataproc cluster, the default port is 9083, and Hive Server2 is configured to use it. In `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`, you will find:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://<master-hostname>:9083</value>
  </property>
```

If you need the HiveServer2 of your cluster:

1. to use the Metastore of another cluster, set `--properties hive:hive.metastore.uris=thrift://<another-cluster-master-hostname>:9083`.
2. or to use the managed Dataproc Metastore Service, follow this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-metastore/docs/quickstart-guide#creating-a-dataproc-cluster), for example:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create example-cluster \
    --dataproc-metastore=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/example-service \
    --region=LOCATION
```

The clusters/Metastore need to be in the same VPC network to communicate with each other through internal IP (or hostname).

Spark in the cluster is automatically configured to use the Hive config `hive.metastore.uris` to find the Metastore, you don't need any additional config in your Spark code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to have a dataproc cluster with its own HiveServer2 but share a common Hive metastore database which is used by multiple clusters. For example, if I create a new dataproc cluster and look up the /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml I see a separate instance of Hive metastore database with these values:
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL -> jdbc:mysql://wl1-hudi-delta-poc-1-m/metastore
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName -> hive
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword -> hive-password

Comment: Yes, this is what I described in the answer, you only need `hive:hive.metastore.uris`, not other properties. There is an in-cluster MySQL on the master node of each cluster, and Metastore is configured to used it, so in the client cluster, you only cares about the external Metastore URI, not the MySQL URI.